# Fetch data from mysql using jquery on clicking button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I fetched a number of data rows in the data table from mysql database. The last column of the table will show a button and i have added id of the button as unique ID from the database. When someone will click on the button, more detailed data from the database from that specific ID will be shown at the right side of the datatable using jquery.

The html code i have

```
<tr><td>John Doe</td><td><button class="btn btn-success" id="<?php print($sms_id) ?>"> Details</button></td><tr>
```

I want to fetch data with correspondent id to the following table

```
<table id="details_sms" class="table table-bordered table-striped">                      
          <tbody id="showdetails">
            <tr><td>From: </td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Amount: </td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Transaction ID:</td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Rec Number: </td><td></td></tr> 
            <tr><td>Full SMS text: </td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td><button class="btn btn-general">Previous</button> </td><td><button class="btn btn-general">Next</button></td></tr>                              
          </tbody>                      
    </table>
```

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "{fetch_details.php}}",
  data: {id = "" } 
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
     $("showdetails").html(result); 
  });
```

fetch_detail.php

```
<?php 
require_once("connection.php");
include("functions.php");


 $get_sms_info = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM sms_in");



while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_sms_info,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $sms_id = $result['id'];
                    $sms_text = $result['sms_text'];
                    $sms_time = $result['sent_dt'];
                    $sender_number = $result['sender_number'];

                preg_match_all('/(\S+)\s+from\s+(\d+).*Fee\s+Tk\s+(\S+)\..*([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})\s+at\s+(.*)/', $sms_text, $matches);

?>
<tr>

                            tr><td>From: </td><td><?php print($matches[5][0]);?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Amount: </td><td><?php print($matches[2][0]);?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Transaction ID:</td><td><?php print($matches[1][0]); ?></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Rec Number: </td><td><?php print($matches[4][0]); ?></td></tr>  
                    <tr><td>Full SMS text: </td><td>$sms_text</td></tr>
                    <tr><td><button class="btn btn-general">Previous</button> </td><td><button class="btn btn-general">Next</button></td></tr>      




</tr>
<?php
}

?>
```

Also Next and previous button will load data corresponding to previous id.

How can i do this using jquery?

Comment: Make a JS function that will add a row to the table. Get data from php via json. On AJAX success just call you function to appending a row to the table.

Comment: Can u pls elaborate with exact code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Never be afraid to separate by functions. You never know where it will come in handy.

> JS
>
> ```
> function addRowToSmsDetailsTable(rowDataFromBackEnd) {
>    let html = '<tr><td>' + rowDataFromBackEnd.col1 + '....</td></tr>';
>    $('#details_sms tr:last').after(html);
> }
>
>
> $.ajax({
>   method: "POST",
>   dataType: 'json', // waiting for json response
>   url: "fetch_details.php",
>   data: {
>       id: 1
>   },
>   success: addRowToSmsDetailsTable // success response handler
> });
> ```
>
> PHP
>
> ```
> <?php 
> require_once("connection.php");
> include("functions.php");
>
> header('Content-Type: application/json'); /* set content type because ajax waiting for json */
>
> define('SMS_INFO_REGEX', '/(\S+)\s+from\s+(\d+).*Fee\s+Tk\s+(\S+)\..*([a-zA-Z0-9]{10})\s+at\s+(.*)/');
>
> $get_sms_info = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM sms_in");
> $resultArray = [];
> while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($get_sms_info,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
>     preg_match_all(SMS_INFO_REGEX, $sms_text, $matches);
>     $resultArray[] = [
>         'id'            => $result['id']
>         'from'          => $matches[5][0],
>         'amount'        => $matches[2][0],
>         'transactionId' => $matches[1][0],
>         'recNumber'     => $matches[4][0],
>         'smsText'       => $result['sms_text']
>     ];
> }
>
> echo json_encode($resultArray);                  
> ?>
> ```

Json is here to standardize interoperability with external and internal interfaces. AJAX will read json as a JS object, and your associative PHP array will be available in the JS function as an object (because we specified dataType: json). I did not check this code, but I think that everything is in order. However, my advice: avoid regular expressions, when it's possible.